# Constant alert when I click in li element using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am having this HTML code:

```
<div id="pagination">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="?page=1">Page 1</a></li>
        <li class="active current"><a href="?page=2">Page 2</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="?page=3">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have this jquery code:

```
$("#paginacion ul li.active").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert();
    $(this).find("a").trigger("click");
});
```

Why when I click in `li` element it an alert appears? I cant stop the alert.

I set the sample in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dmoraroca/h5czs53e/2/embedded/result/

Let me know if you can open the link, thanks.

Comment: Just remove alert(); ?

Comment: `event.stopPropagation()` doesn't stop the execution of the function who's calling it.

Comment: Also, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Events are bubbling up so when you trigger `click` on `a` it will bubble up to `li`, that's why you create an _endless-loop_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the event handler, you are triggering the click event over the `<a>` tag that is inside `<li>` tag. So you are in an infinite loop of events, and you have infinite alerts.

Comment: how can I call the click event of a element then?

Comment: alert was only to know if when I clicked there I had some result, anyway what I have is a function which really change the page inside a element. In href i have javascript:void(0). What I want to do it is to execute the function inside click event of A Element. My initial sample was to know the infinite alerts. You answered right for me. How can I execute function inside click event of A Element?

Comment: Can you probe a solution like that proposed by @Ehsan Sajjad?

Answer (score 1):

Why you can't do this:

```
jQuery("#paginacion ul li.active").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert();
    window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); // redirect to link address
    // do what you want here
});
```

or:

```
jQuery("#paginacion ul li.active > a").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert();
    // do what you want here
});
```

### Snippet:

```js
 jQuery("#paginacion ul li.active").click(function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            alert();
            window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        });
```

```css
.current {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.active {
    background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="paginacion">
<ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="?page=1">Page 1</a></li>
    <li class="current"><a href="?page=2">Page 2</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="?page=3">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: OP need open the link!!